# Signal Slot connect under windows, connect NOT under linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, signals-slots

I'm developing Qt applications that have to run under Windows and Linux. First I test functions under Windows, because it's easier to debug. After that I run a test under Linux (compiled using colinux).

Now I discovered that there are few signal slot connections, which work under windows do NOT work under Linux. Using `QErrorMessage` under Linux there are messages like no such signal linuxDebugSignal()" or "no such slot logStartedSlot()". But all signals and slots are implemented, the moc_file shows them and all connections return true under Windows.

EDIT:

header:

```
#include <QtCore/QObject>

class class : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
Class(void);
~Class(void);

private slots:  

void checkIniFileSlot();

void logStartedSlot();

void linuxDebugSlot();

signals:

void logMessageSignal(QString, QString, QString, int);

void checkIniFileSignal();

void stopLogSignal();

void linuxDebugSignal();
};
```

source:

```
#include "qerrormessage.h"
#include "class.h"

Class::Class(void)
{
    QErrorMessage::qtHandler();

    //works
    connect(this, SIGNAL(checkIniFileSignal()), this, SLOT(checkIniFileSlot()));

    emit checkIniFileSignal();
}
Class::~Class(void)
{
}

void Class::checkIniFileSlot()
{
    m_Log = new Log();

    bool bStatus;

    //works
    bStatus = connect(this, SIGNAL(stopLogSignal()),
                    m_Log, SLOT(stopLogSlot()));

    //works
    bStatus = connect(this, SIGNAL(logMessageSignal(QString, QString, QString, int)), 
                    m_Log, SLOT(logMessageSlot(QString, QString, QString, int)));

    //works NOT no such slot logStartedSlot()
    bStatus = connect(m_Log, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(logStartedSlot()));

    //works NOT no such signal linuxDebugSIgnal()
    bStatus = connect(this, SIGNAL(linuxDebugSignal()), this, SLOT(linuxDebugSlot()));              

}
void CWNcPlcServer::linuxDebugSlot()
{
    emit logMessageSignal("", "linuxDebugSlot","",Log::LOG_DEBUG);
}
void CWNcPlcServer::logStartedSlot()
{
    emit logMessageSignal("", "logStartedSlot","",Log::LOG_DEBUG);
}
```

Sorry for not adding code. I meant this question in general, if there are known obstacles when porting from windows to linux. As you can see, the working signals/slots are not really different to the not working signals/slots.

I'm developing on a Win7 32 Bit System, colinux is running on a WinXP 32 Bit VM, both have the same Qt Version.
I not explicitly invoke qmake, I put .h .cpp .pro in a working directory, everything else is part of that colinux distribution I use. I used it for a longer time without having problems, now I'm trying to get some more informations about it.

SOLUTION:

So, because of the bad voting or anything else, I'm not able to add the answer.

The Problem was part of a server application which is implemented as a dynamic library. When a dummyclient is startet, it connects to this server to start up all server functions. This dummyclient does nothing else and has no other interfaces/communications to this server. When new server functions are implemented, we change server.dll, dummyclient.dll remains old. It seems to be no problem on windows.

When changing the server.so file on linux without updating the dummyclient.so the newer signals and slots could not be found. But you can see in the example code, these signals and slots that are not working have nothing to do with the dummyclient!? They are used for server internal tasks. When compiling dummyclient with new server.so and server.h it works, all signal slot connections are established.

I hope this was understandable.

I'm new to development for linux. Is this a normal reaction? What about dynamic libraries!?

Comment: "Anyone with an idea where to start looking?" I recommend a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you invoke `qmake` before building your project under Linux?

Comment: I would suggest to post some code prior to asking a question. You can connect slots and signals in multiple ways, maybe you are using the wrong Macros ?

Comment: At first glance it looks like moc might not have run correctly. How exactly did you compile it on Linux?

Comment: Another issue you might want to consider: Are  you using the same version of Qt on both systems? Are you building them both in 64-bit mode (or in 32-bit mode) ? Are there any other differences in your build environment? Also, user2079303 had a great idea: Put together a minimal sample for us, and post the code.

Comment: Slot functions must be defined under `public slot` or `private slot`. Do you define slot function like this ?

Answer (score 2):

if you define your signals and slots connection like this:

lets say the class is called "SomeClass" and you have a signal "someSignal"
and you connecting to a slot in "DifferentClass" called "someSlot"

```
//DifferentClass *foo;

QObject::connect(this, &SomeClass::someSignal, foo, &DifferentClass::someSlot);
```

If you connect like this you will get compiler errors if the signals/slots are incompatible or dont exist, this should help with making sure you code is correct before you compile instead of getting a log message at run time telling you that your signal slot wont work

Note: you dont have to put in parameters, the compiler will work out if they are compatible